# how moodle save user quiz response in database?

Tags: php, moodle

how moodle1.9 save user attempt quiz result in database and which tables are updated when any quiz has been attempted by user?

Please guide me.

If possible please updated me, which functions are used to insert user quiz attempted data in moodle1.9 database?

Comment: Relevant: Moodle Developer Documentation - http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development

Comment: @vkwave Does your question involve programming?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: I think it does. It seems like he's working on some Moodle extension. Question should be tagged php as well.

Comment: @Roberto  exactally, i should add php tag also.
Thanks to all. I have found solution by my self effort. Thanks for updating me.

Comment: @vkwave: if your solution differs from the ones posted here, I strongly advise you to post it here, since someone from the community could have the same problem in the future...

Comment: @vkwave Please post the solution you found, and complete the question-lifecycle.

Comment: Dear All, i did not find any solution so i code it by myself and it is working perfect at my end. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the `attempt.php` file (Moodle 1.9.7):

```
$attempt = quiz_create_attempt($quiz, $attemptnumber);
```

Then:

```
if (!$attempt->id = insert_record('quiz_attempts', $attempt)) {
            error('Could not create new attempt');
        }
```

From `locallib.php`:

```
/**
 * Creates an object to represent a new attempt at a quiz
 *
 * Creates an attempt object to represent an attempt at the quiz by the current
 * user starting at the current time. The ->id field is not set. The object is
 * NOT written to the database.
 * @return object                The newly created attempt object.
 * @param object $quiz           The quiz to create an attempt for.
 * @param integer $attemptnumber The sequence number for the attempt.
 */
function quiz_create_attempt($quiz, $attemptnumber) {
    global $USER, $CFG;

    if (!$attemptnumber > 1 or !$quiz->attemptonlast or !$attempt = get_record('quiz_attempts', 'quiz', $quiz->id, 'userid', $USER->id, 'attempt', $attemptnumber-1)) {
        // we are not building on last attempt so create a new attempt
        $attempt->quiz = $quiz->id;
        $attempt->userid = $USER->id;
        $attempt->preview = 0;
        if ($quiz->shufflequestions) {
            $attempt->layout = quiz_repaginate($quiz->questions, $quiz->questionsperpage, true);
        } else {
            $attempt->layout = $quiz->questions;
        }
    }

    $timenow = time();
    $attempt->attempt = $attemptnumber;
    $attempt->sumgrades = 0.0;
    $attempt->timestart = $timenow;
    $attempt->timefinish = 0;
    $attempt->timemodified = $timenow;
    $attempt->uniqueid = question_new_attempt_uniqueid();

    return $attempt;
}
```

Please refer to the source code for major details.